# Можно ли преобразовать строку вида списка в сам список в питоне?

Tags: python

К примеру, у меня в файле запись:

```
"['1', '2', '3']"
```

При чтении данных из файла и выводе первого значения списка `[0]`, выводится первый символ строки `[`, а не значение списка, то есть строка из файла автоматически преобразуется в переменную типа `str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

list_ = ast.literal_eval("['1', '2', '3']")
```

---

из файла:

```
import ast

with open(filename) as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

---

PS если же в файле будет сохранен *корректный* JSON файл, то можно будет воспользоваться [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) / [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), но в вашем случае используются одинарные кавычки для обрамления строк- это нарушает правила JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
s  = "['1', '2', '3']" 
print(type(eval(s)))
```

Comment: Если нужно всего лишь распарсить список, то `eval` - это очень плохое решение. Вообще лучше избегать использования `eval`. Почитайте вот это: [И снова про опасность eval()](https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/)

Comment: Как альтернатива, если источник данных доверенный, почему нет? Возможно eval и работает быстрее.

Comment: Потому что есть узкоспециализированный безопасный вариант в виде `literal_eval`. По поводу того что работает быстрее тоже очень сильно сомневаюсь - нужно замерять.

Comment: По моим измерениям eval оказался на ~25% быстрее.